# JLabel get on top layer when its property changed

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

theres some problem in my swing? program.
i searched it in here but theres no answer so i post this.

heres the sample code:

```
public class main{

    private static JFrame frame;

    private static JLayeredPane layered;

    private static JPanel panel1;
    private static JPanel panel2;
    private static JPanel bg_change;
    private static JLabel txt_bg;
    private static JLabel txt_change;

    private static JButton btnBG;
    private static JButton btnTEXT;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(0,0,500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(null);


            layered = new JLayeredPane();
            layered.setBounds(0,0,frame.getWidth(),frame.getHeight());
            layered.setLayout(null);
            layered.setOpaque(true);
            layered.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            frame.add(layered);

                panel1 = new JPanel();
                panel1.setBounds(10,10,300,300);
                panel1.setOpaque(true);
                panel1.setLayout(null);
                panel1.setBackground(Color.RED);
                layered.add(panel1,0);

                    btnBG = new JButton("BTN_BG");
                    btnBG.setBounds(100,50,0,0);
                    btnBG.setSize(btnBG.getPreferredSize());
                    panel1.add(btnBG);

                    btnTEXT = new JButton("BTN_TXT");
                    btnTEXT.setBounds(100,100,0,0);
                    btnTEXT.setSize(btnTEXT.getPreferredSize());
                    panel1.add(btnTEXT);

                panel2 = new JPanel();
                panel2.setBounds(50,50,300,300);
                panel2.setOpaque(true);
                panel2.setLayout(null);
                panel2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                layered.add(panel2,1);

                    bg_change = new JPanel();
                    bg_change.setBounds(240,240,50,50);
                    bg_change.setOpaque(true);
                    bg_change.setLayout(null);
                    bg_change.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

                    txt_change = new JLabel("TESTTESTETST");
                    txt_change.setBounds(240,30,0,0);
                    txt_change.setSize(txt_change.getPreferredSize());
                    txt_change.setOpaque(false);

                    panel2.add(bg_change);
                    panel2.add(txt_change);


        frame.repaint();
        addListner();

    }

    public static void addListner() {
        btnBG.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                bg_change.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

            }
        });

        btnTEXT.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                txt_change.setText("CLICKCLICKCLICKK");
                txt_change.setSize(txt_change.getPreferredSize());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

click buttons then each target components get changed their back ground color or text.
buttons work but i want target components stay behind red panel.
how should i do?

thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problemes:

1. an "int" parameter is different than an "Integer" parameter. The layered pane expects you to use an Integer to specify the constraint for the layer. Read the `Container.add(…)` API for the different overloaded methods to see the difference between "int" and "Object" as a parameter for the add(… ) method.
2. components with a higher Integer value are painted on top.

So a couple of changes:

```
//layered.add(panel1, 0);
layered.add(panel1, new Integer(1));

...

//layered.add(panel2,1);
layered.add(panel2, new Integer(0));
```

Also, you should NOT be using all static variables and methods. This is an indication of poor design.

I suggest you read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Layered Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for more information and examples with better structured code.